# SQL Clause Help in a VBA Procedure

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I've got a spreadsheet with one Employee sheet (approx. 80k) rows, and I'm trying to find expert employees (Skill_Prof = 5) that are the only person in that Branch with that particular Skill_Title. My code so far is:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT Branch, Skill_Title, Employee FROM [Employee$] WHERE Skill_Prof = 5"

rs.Open strSQL, cn
```

My problem is trying to determine if I need to use COUNT, SUM, or other function to find the cases where there's only 1 expert employee with that Skill_Title in that Branch.

Does anyone have ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Its long ago but i think you need a count inside a sub select. That can not be done in a single liner. But 80 k is not that big. If it is a task which is not that often to do. Just use a for next loop. Not elegant but fast enough. first select distinct Skill_Title from... And then some querys with count to get those which are have just one person... It is possible to do that with one sql statement but that will take more time to create as it might be worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT e.Branch, e.Skill_Title, e.Employee 
FROM [Employee$] AS e
WHERE e.Skill_Prof = 5
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [Employee$]
  WHERE Employee <> e.Employee AND Branch = e.Branch AND Skill_Title = e.Skill_Title AND Skill_Prof = e.Skill_Prof
)
```

Or with a join:

```
SELECT e.Branch, e.Skill_Title, e.Employee 
FROM [Employee$] AS e INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Branch, Skill_Title 
    FROM [Employee$] 
    GROUP BY Branch, Skill_Title
    HAVING SUM(IIF(Skill_Prof = 5, 1, 0)) = 1
) AS g ON g.Branch = e.Branch AND g.Skill_Title = e.Skill_Title
WHERE e.Skill_Prof = 5
```

Comment: This is very helpful! I'm trying to test it out, and getting some interesting results. Will this account for the two conditions? 1) experts at the 5 level for a given skill (skill_title) and 2) the only expert in that branch in a particular skill_title?

Comment: I did not see in your code: *with that particular Skill_Title* so I will edit in a few mins.

Comment: Tested the inner join and it works perfectly. Thanks forpas!